# i am trying to code a quiz with python but its not working

Tags: python

i am coding a quiz in python. everything seems to work until i try to input the answer. i am very new to this. also can somebody explain what an indentation block is and an example of it.
this is the code:

```
>>> print('physics quiz')
physics quiz
>>> print('round 1')
round 1
>>> print('what is the 1st stage of a stars life?')
what is the 1st stage of a stars life?
>>> print('a...protostar')
a...protostar
>>> print('b...nebula')
b...nebula
>>> print('c...red giant')
c...red giant
>>>answer=int(input('you have 5 seconds'))
you have 5 seconds
'a'
if answer=='a':
  print('correct')
else:
  print('incorrect, it was protostar')
```

Comment: To get your code correctly formatted you'll have to put a newline before and after it and indent every line of in your code by an additional 4 spaces.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would be better to post code that members can easily reproduce so that we can quickly see what errors there are, and what possible solutions might work. See here for more: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

in this line

```
answer=int(input('you have 5 seconds'))
```

you are converting input to int, therefore it will fail once int() can't convert input